# Unable to install bind9 on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, server, bind

I cant install the bind server I was trying to do clean rap cache and update.

This is what I get after running the `apt-get install bind8` / `apt-get install -f bind9` :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bind9 : Depends: libbind9-80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
         Depends: libdns81 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
         Depends: libisc83 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
         Depends: libisccc80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
         Depends: libisccfg82 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
         Depends: liblwres80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2 is to** be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: any one can help here?

Answer (score 2):

Ok found the solution, I had to update my system, so i went to software sources and then I Checked all checkboxes in the 3 first tabs Ubuntu software,Other software,Updates
after everything was checked I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then to install bind9

```
sudo apt-get install bind9
```

Comment: It is quite acceptable to mark your own answer as the solution to your problem. See [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2386/theres-no-way-to-mark-a-question-solved-when-you-figure-it-out-yourself).